# Ferromagnetic Instability at van Hove singularity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

In a 2D square lattice with half-filled electron, It's generally understood that the nesting effect on Fermi surface will cause the antiferromagnetic instability. However, there are a few literature stating that 'if Fermi surface is in the vicinity of van Hove singularity, it can create ferromagnetic instability'.

I cannot understand why it is the case. Is there any qualitative picture (like nesting in AFM) that can explain this situation?